# MySQL Insert one row multiple times in one query

Tags: mysql

I need to insert one row to MySQL many times, and also i have other rows that i want insert many times too. For now i am doing that query:

```
INSERT INTO 

`admin_alpha`.`some_name` (`id`, `other_id`, `another_id`, `user_id`, `somedata`, `data2`, `somedata3`) 

VALUES 

(NULL, 'VALUE1', '-1', '1', '1', '', ''),
(NULL, 'VALUE1', '-1', '1', '1', '', ''),
(NULL, 'VALUE1', '-1', '1', '1', '', ''),
(NULL, 'VALUE2', '-1', '1', '2', '', ''),
(NULL, 'VALUE2', '-1', '1', '2', '', ''),
(NULL, 'VALUE3', '-1', '1', '3', '', ''),
(NULL, 'VALUE3', '-1', '1', '3', '', ''),
(NULL, 'VALUE3', '-1', '1', '3', '', ''),
(NULL, 'VALUE3', '-1', '1', '3', '', '')
```

And it works, but preparing query for above 600+ rows, and repat each row few times, take some time.

There is any other way to do it faster? I mean something like this (my knowledge about SQL syntax is poor but i belive You can understand what i mean) :

```
INSERT INTO 

`admin_alpha`.`some_name` (`id`, `other_id`, `another_id`, `user_id`, `somedata`, `data2`, `somedata3`) 

VALUES 

(NULL, 'VALUE1', '-1', '1', '1', '', '') copy x 3,
(NULL, 'VALUE2', '-1', '1', '2', '', '') copy x 2,
(NULL, 'VALUE3', '-1', '1', '3', '', '') copy x 4
```

Thanks for help.

Comment: Nope. Carry on.

Comment: One way you can do is to create a stored procedure and use these insert query in the looping statement to get the row inserted multiple times.

Comment: If the slow part is simply creating the query (as opposed to executing it), you could use a server-side language (PHP, Python, etc.) to generate the SQL statement.

Answer (score -1):

Write a script with Python or JS or Golang to generate the insertion part SQL dynamically in a for loop.